# Segfault during fclose() despite correct file pointer

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, memory, segmentation-fault

- Happens consistently during object destruction;
- The file pointer values right after fopen() and right before fclose() are the same;
- fclose() is called only once in object destructor;
- The object is created statically and destroyed at the end of the scope
- The file is handled only in one thread

File opening:

```
logOutFile_fd = fopen(logOutFile,"w");
if (logOutFile_fd==NULL) {
  /* omitted */
}
```

File closing:

```
if (logOutFile_fd!=NULL) {
  fflush(logOutFile_fd);
  fclose(logOutFile_fd);
}
```

I compiled with "-g3" and ran through gdb, here is the full backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff6f8d3f8 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x00007ffff6f8effa in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x00007ffff6fcf6f9 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x00007ffff6fd7f4a in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#4  0x00007ffff6fdbc1c in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#5  0x00007ffff6fc52c3 in fclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
#6  0x0000000000402733 in t_netInterface::~t_netInterface (this=0x7ffff5f50cf0, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at connect.cpp:59
No locals.
#7  0x00000000004022fc in pthreadTask (pthData=0x7fffffffe070) at client.cpp:131
        netInterface = {id = 162, currTime = {tv_sec = 0, tv_usec = 0}, dbg_time_sync = {tv_sec = 0, tv_usec = 0}, dbg_time_prev = 0, dbg_time_now = 0, 
          dbg_time_dprev = 0, dbg_time_dnow = 0, dbg_ch0_len = 0, datems = 0, timeMarkSet = {0 <repeats 12 times>}, chunk = 0, chunk_ch = 0 '\000', 
          chunk_dt = 0, chunk_H = 0 '\000', chunk_L = 0 '\000', fpd = 0x0, logOutFile = 0x0, logOutFile_fd = 0x7fffec038f30, 
          dataOutFile = 0x7fffec001c10 "(\b", dataOutFile_fd = 0x7fffec03a580, globalLogFile_fd = 0x7fffec0009d0, dir0 = 0x7fffec001d20 "(\b", sockfd = 11, 
          portno = 34000, serv_addr = {sin_family = 2, sin_port = 53380, sin_addr = {s_addr = 2717952192}, sin_zero = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}, 
          poll_d = {{fd = 11, events = 1, revents = 0}}, f_ret = 0, channelBuffers = 0x7fffec000920, channelBuffIter = 0x7fffec0008e0, 
          channelDataTypeH = 1284, valSigned = 0, dbgFlag = 0, dataPath = 0x7fffec006d50 "(\b", addr_str = 0x7fffec002530 "192.168.0.162", 
          buffChar = 0x7fffec002d40 "(\b", wasConnected = 0}
        data = 0x7fffffffe070
        out_buffer = 64
        in_buffer = {0 <repeats 8192 times>}
        pid = 162
        tid = 162
        logOutFile_fd = 0x7fffec038f30
        res = 1
        rcvDataSizeBytes = 0
        retv = 0
        cc = 2003
        active = 0
        uptimeSec = 27134
        globalLogName = 0x7fffec0008c0 "x"
        globalLogFile_fd = 0x7fffec0009d0
#8  0x00007ffff7328684 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
No symbol table info available.
#9  0x00007ffff705eefd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
No symbol table info available.
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

**edit:** I've tried to shuffle deallocators around and now it definitely looks like memory trashing somewhere between class constructor and destructor. I'm going to be reimplementing some things so the question can be considered as closed. Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: Generally speaking segfaults are reported on the Line **AFTER** the segfault has occurred because the instruction pointer `rip` has already incremented. Without the source of the function you're calling we have no idea what could be causing it though. Please post your code.

Comment: Please reduce your program to the shortest **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. Please copy-paste that entire short program into your question. See [mcve] for more information.

Comment: *Happens consistently during object destruction* What object? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Is this a multi-threaded application? How is `t_NetInterface` constructed and destructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A crash in fclose like this indicates that the `FILE` data structure involved has been corrupted, probably by an invalid pointer use elsewhere in the program.

Your best bet is probably a memory checking tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)